# React not updating when I make changes to this .jsx file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG4oX.png)This is my first react app and i tried changing the app.js file but its not updating.
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: How are you running it

Comment: did you run it in development built with `npm start` ?

Comment: yes i did on terminal, npm start

Comment: You haven't save the file. I can see the `M` (for modified) in the tab of App.js file.

Comment: @Amila Senadheera I think he had saved the file. Otherwise there will be a grey circle in the tab in the place of x (close) icon

Comment: yeah i've saved it

Comment: @Reactface are you accessing the site on localhost:3000? Are you using Create-reaact-app?

Comment: Add a bit more context to the question itself. What framework are you running and what have you tried to diagnose the problem?